# How to use Mininet in GUI version?

Tags: mininet

I'm new in networking and passionate in learning more about SDN and OpenFlow Network. After some searching on the internet, I've found that there's an emulator software called "Mininet". I hear that this software supports simulation of switch better than GNS3. Now, my problem is where can I use Mininet in GUI?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GUI actually in mininet. Mininet emulates network and you use
commands through terminal and mininet terminal environment.

The only GUI I know on mininet is miniedit to create topology via a graphic environment instead of writing a python script.

Comment: Thanks for your response :) After some searching on google, I finally found that the miniedit is already included inside mininet installation package. The path is in: mininet/examples/miniedit.py

Answer (score 1):

There is no GUI to mininet. But you can use MiniEdit provided as example python file with mininet installation.

If you have installed mininet using Virtual machine, probably you would be looking for a simplest GUI.
I am using **Fast Light Window Manager** to setup GUI quickly with minimal configuration. But you are free to choose KDE, Gnome or another desktop environments.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install xinit flwm
```

Now you can start X11 session (GUI) in the VM Console

```
$ startx
```

An empty GUI will open where you can right click and select the program you want to execute.

Start mininet edit using the provided example with mininet

```
$ sudo ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py
```